# React MUI ProgressBar not rendering on value change

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, progress-bar

I have a functional component where I am using the MUI progress bar that I want to display but when the progress bar loads its still at the progress I set at the first step.
Also I am calling an API and processing the results in one of the functions. What am I doing wrong ?

```
function LinearProgressWithLabel(props: LinearProgressProps & { value: number }) {
    return (
      <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Box sx={{ width: '100%', mr: 1 }}>
          <LinearProgress variant="determinate" {...props} />
        </Box>
        <Box sx={{ minWidth: 35 }}>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">{`${Math.round(
            props.value,
          )}%`}</Typography>
        </Box>
      </Box>
    );
  }

export const Search = (props) => {

    const { onSearchComplete } = props;

    const [msgBox, setMsgBox] = useState(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [progress, setProgress] = useState(10);
    const onSearch = async () => {

        setLoading(true);

        const emails = contacts
            .filter(x => x.isChecked)
            .map(item => item.emailAddress);
        
        setProgress(30); //this is where I am manually setting the progress. 

        try {
            const searchResults = await AppApi.search(emails);

            let userList = [];
            setProgress(70); // I want to manually set the percentage here 


            for (let i = 0; i < searchResults.length; i++) {
               //processing the list here 
            }


            onSearchComplete(userList); //passing on the results to another component
        } catch (err) {
            console.log({ err });
            setMsgBox({ message: `${err.message}`, type: 'error' });
        }

        setLoading(false);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        onSearch();
      }, [progress]);


    return (
        <Box>
            
            {loading ?   <LinearProgressWithLabel value={progress} />:
            <Box>{msgBox && (<a style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }} onClick={() => setMsgBox(null)} title="Click  to dismiss"><MessageBox type={msgBox.type || 'info'}>{msgBox.message}</MessageBox></a>)}</Box>}


        </Box>
    );
}
```

Comment: `progress` should not be a dependency for the `useEffect`

Comment: shall I implement a new useEffect hook ? @gerrod

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, your `useEffect` hook has the wrong dependencies. `onSearch` looks like it has two dependencies that could change - `contacts` and `onSearchComplete`, so the effect hook should actually be written as:

```
useEffect(() => {
    onSearch();
}, [contacts, onSearchComplete]);
```

Depending on how `onSearchComplete` is defined, you might find that your effect re-runs more frequently than it should; you can either solve this by making `onSearchComplete` a callback:

```
const OtherComponent = () => {
    const onSearchComplete = useCallback(userList => {
        // ----- 8< -----
    }, [...]);
}
```

Or wrapping the callback in a ref -

```
const Search = ({ onSearchComplete }) => {
    const onSearchCompleteRef = useRef();
    onSearchCompleteRef.current = onSearchComplete;

    const onSearch = async () => {
        // ----- 8< -----
        onSearchCompleteRef.current(userList);
    }

    // Now you don't need onSearchComplete as a dependency
    useEffect(() => { 
        onSearch(); 
    }, [contacts]);
};
```

#### Edit

The reason you're not seeing the "updated" progress is because the processing of the results happens on the same render cycle as you updating the progress bar. The only way to get around that would be to introduce an artificial delay when you're processing the results:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    onSearchCompleteRef.current();
    setLoading(false);
}, 100);
```

[I created a CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-cookies-mnpu7t?file=/src/App.tsx) to show this.

Comment: hi @gerrod but this doesnt resolve my progressBar render

Comment: Can you provide a minimal repro in a code sandbox? Without seeing the rest of what your code is doing I can't see a problem.

Comment: Ok so i can explain - whats is happening here is that the Saearch functional component is being called from another component with an array of emails. Now I am calling an API in the onSaearch function and while the search is happening i want to display a progress bar.

Comment: @JainamShah - I think it's just a timing issue, see the updated answer ☝️